# Can I display the name of Activex CheckBox without using it's name in the VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I want to display when I tick an Activex CheckBox, except that in the VBA code I don't want its name so that it can be generalized to all Activex CheckBoxes.

[image]

Comment: [Event triggered by ANY checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517730) looks promising.

Comment: I recommend to stay away from ActiveX and use FormControls if possible. ActiveX is known to is full of bugs and can cause many strange issues. So if you can, go with the FormControl CheckBoxes.